# XSLT: Translate special characters

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to convert below XML through XSLT by translating any special characters (approved) into general characters. Please advise

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:File xmlns:wd="urn:com.test/bsvc">
    <wd:Entry>
        <wd:Name>ABCá</wd:Name>
        <wd:ID>123</wd:ID>
        <wd:Amount>10</wd:Amount>
    </wd:Entry>
    <wd:Entry>
        <wd:Name>DEFé</wd:Name>
        <wd:ID>456</wd:ID>
        <wd:Amount>20</wd:Amount>
    </wd:Entry>
    <wd:Entry>
        <wd:Name>GHIÿ</wd:Name>
        <wd:ID>789</wd:ID>
        <wd:Amount>30</wd:Amount>
    </wd:Entry>
</wd:File>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.test/bsvc" exclude-result-prefixes="wd">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:File/wd:Entry">
                        
            <Details>
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:ID"/>
                </ID>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Name"/>
                </Name>
            </Details>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output generated:**

```
<Details>
   <ID>123</ID>
   <Name>ABCá</Name>
</Details>
<Details>
   <ID>456</ID>
   <Name>DEFé</Name>
</Details>
<Details>
   <ID>789</ID>
   <Name>GHIÿ</Name>
</Details>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<Details>
   <ID>123</ID>
   <Name>ABCa</Name>
</Details>
<Details>
   <ID>456</ID>
   <Name>DEFe</Name>
</Details>
<Details>
   <ID>789</ID>
   <Name>GHIy</Name>
</Details>
```

I would like to convert below XML through XSLT by translating any special characters (approved) into general characters. Please advise

Comment: If you find a list of all latin characters with accents, you could use `translate()`.